# Google tag manager conversion value undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I use Google Tag Manager with Google Ads and try to track conversions. I can't record the conversion value from a datalayer.
Can you help me?
My setting attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create new Data Layer Variable.

Use Data Layer Variable Name: `ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue`.

Then you can use this variable in your Google Ads Conversion Tag.

Comment: Asker (incorrectly) accepted this answer within another answer, which got removed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to variable
2. create a new variable
3. Create from data layer variable
4. use variable name " ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue "
5. name the variable custom name that you called for customer parameter
6. done